# Why does div with "display: flex" and "position: fixed" doesn't occupy the full available width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I noticed that when `div` has `position: fixed` and `display: flex`, it doesn't occupy the full available width like normal `div`s do.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

.content {
  background-color: #bbb;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Title</div>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>

<div class="container fixed">
  <div>Title</div>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

[image]

How could I change my CSS so that the second container occupy the full available width like that first one does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why?** is already answered by [Michael_B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46507466/why-does-div-with-display-flex-and-position-fixed-doesnt-occupy-the-full#answer-46507485)

> ... it is out-of-flow ...

*What you can also do* is to size the `fixed` element  from **left and right coordonates** instead `width:100%;` that is more often a trouble maker than helpfull.

If it is a direct-child of body, it can also inherits margins .

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin-left:inherit;
  margin-right:inherit;
}

.content {
  background-color: #bbb;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Title</div>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>

<div class="container fixed">
  <div>Title</div>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The first container represents an in-flow block-level element. Such elements are designed to stack vertically. This means they occupy the full width of their parent container.

The second container represents an absolutely-positioned element (fixed positioning is a form of absolute positioning). This means the element is out-of-flow and doesn't take up any space.

Unlike in-flow block-level elements, absolutely-positioned elements are not designed to stack vertically. So there's no automatic full width. The default width and height of an absolutely-positioned element is based on its content. To override default sizing, set your own lengths.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%; /* new */
  /* alternatively, you can use left: 0 and right: 0 */
}

.content {
  background-color: #bbb;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Title</div>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>

<div class="container fixed">
  <div>Title</div>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Both `width: 100%` and `left: 0; right: 0` result in a width that is wider than the first container.

Comment: Browsers normally give the `body` element a default margin of 6-8px. The first container, with the in-flow block-level container, respects that margin. The second container, removed from the normal flow, ignores the margin. Just add `body { margin: 0; }` to your code: https://jsfiddle.net/jdf9ugy9/

Comment: Interesting. So, even if the containers had an outer container (whose parent is `body`), there wouldn't be a way to style the outer container to achieve the desired result, without styling the `body`? http://jsbin.com/vivuvopeno/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: When you set an element to `position: fixed`, its reference becomes the highest level containing block (`html` / viewport). It ignores all other containers.

Comment: What can we do then if the outer container has margin-left/right? http://jsbin.com/yihazuzivu/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @MishaMoroshko apply the margins values to the the left and right coordonates, give up width xx% http://jsbin.com/ginugiyupu/1/edit?html,css,output or apply margins to that container too http://jsbin.com/guqufonivu/1/edit?html,css,output (also: no width given, just coordonates to size it) remember : width:100% is usually a trouble maker. If width is less that the screen width, then it can be used with margins : http://jsbin.com/ceqimoxaqo/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `width: 100%;` , otherwise the width will be just as wide as the contents of the element.

Also, you should add `html, body { margin: 0; }` to avoid the default margins.

BTW: That has nothing to do with `display: flex`, but only with `position: fixed`...

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  background-color: #bbb;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Title</div>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>

<div class="container fixed">
  <div>Title</div>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```